# Unable to view symbols when debugging GNU Fortran in LLDB

Tags: macos, fortran, clang, lldb

This is a follow-up question to a question [posted previously on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809626/fortran-debugging-with-gdb-on-mac-os).

When I compile with the -g (or -gdwarf-2) flag in GNU Fortran (GNU Fortran (MacPorts gcc5 5.3.0_0) 5.3.0) I am unable to examine symbols.  If I use the "frame variable" command I do not get the list of local variables.  If I use the "print" command with a symbol, nothing is printed.

I can get breakpoints to work by using the appropriate name (I look at the output from nm to get the mangled name).  The source code is displayed in the debugger, so lldb is understanding at least some of the debugging information.

Answer (score 0):

lldb has no support for Fortran at present.  In particular, since lldb relies on the clang/swift type system representations, which also don't support Fortran, the expression parser won't work at all.  There is Go support that gets frame variable working without having to make a full Go clang frontend.  That same path could be followed to get some Fortran support.  But there's nobody working on this that I am aware of.