# profiling or debugging fortran on an M1 Mac

Tags: debugging, fortran, openmp, apple-m1

I am trying to debug and profile (ideally line-by-line time spent) Fortran code on an M1 Mac. Most commands I tried don't seem to work for Fortran and/or M1.

- `gdb` seems outdated and won't run
- `lldb` complains that it does not work on M1.
- I tried Time Profiler within Instruments, but I cannot make any sense of the recorded output.

If someone could tell me which commands or flags are needed or show and example, that'd be greatly appreciated!

Context: I'm trying to find some bottlenecks for optimization of serial code and in addition, an OpenMP version of my subroutine just stops with *"Illegal instruction: 4"*, so I'm trying to find out why this is happening (stack and `OMP_STACKSIZE` is large).

---

**EDIT** - To give some more details:

I am compiling with `gfortran` (Homebrew GCC 13.1.0). So wanted to compile with `-p -pg` option and run `gdb ./a.out`, but installing `gdb` fails with

*"gdb: The x86_64 architecture is required for this software."*

also adding the `-pg` option during compilation does not seem to work. It complains that *"ld: library not found for -lgcrt1.o"* but this file is nowhere to be found (neither in homebrew nor on the Xcode SDK packages) and `brew install glibc` (of which *gcrt1.o* seems to be part of) also does not work (*"glibc: Linux is required for this software."*).

I managed to start `lldb ./a.out`, but this seems useless to me. I can set a break point, but if I try to print out a variable (e.g. `p (int) ix`, I get *"error: Could not find type system for language fortran95: TypeSystem for language fortran95 doesn't exist"*.

So in summary just stepping through any simple little fortran program in a debugger does not work for me on an M1 Mac. If someone knows how to make this work or where to find those missing libraries, that would greatly be appreciated. Extra credit would be a line-by-line-time-spent output to help me find where the bottleneck is.

Comment: This is a quite vague question. First, which compiler/version are you using?

Comment: `gfortran` from `Homebrew GCC 13.1.0`, mostly. Sorry about the vagueness, but it is a problem not specific to a particular code and most related answers are outdated (other architecture or languages), so I hope this will be useful not only for me. Let me know if I can be more specific on some aspects.

Comment: Is your code compiled for ARM? An illegal instruction hints that it might not be the case. Show the specific versions of the software you are using and the exact error messages. No "complains that", just copy the message. Plese note that software recommendations are off-topic here and should be asked at https://softrec.stackexchange.com

Comment: Remember, all software that you try **must be compiled for Apple M1-2**. Trying some version downloaded somewhere that is compiled for x86-64 is hopeless. When asking to solve a specific problem you must indicate the exact versions you have.

Comment: Yes, I am compiling for on the M1 Mac for the M1 Mac

Comment: There are a million questions asking for "how can I do X" and people recommend command line tools. I don't see why this is closed for asking for a recommendation.

Comment: @JohnSmith Because the answer for "how to debug" is: use a debugger. You say that the usual debuggers do not work for you and asking for a different one. But you should first try to find out why the usual ones do not work. I and others have asked for details how those debuggers you mentioned do not work for you, because they should. The main point is that tools like GDB really **should work** on ARM just fine. If they do not work for you, you must show some details. You probably have some incorrect version. Alas, you did not even indicate what version you have!

Comment: *"Yes, I am compiling for on the M1 Mac for the M1 Mac"* Yes, But I wrote that all the software you are trying to use must be the correct M1 version as well. Show us the specific versions of the software you tried. Tell us where you got them.

Comment: Regarding your last comment, though, remember, you did NOT ask "how can I do X", you asked "I am looking for tools to debug and profile" and only made the edit later. I am not voting for reopen because they are other reasons for the closer, explained in my previois two comments. The solution is simple, just provide the necessary details. You yourself wrote "Let me know if I can be more specific on some aspects". I spent a lot of time explaining how you can be. Please spend at least some time being more specific.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава at some point `gbd` was not working on Mac M1/M2. I don't know if it has changed since then. A common workaround was to install ARM Linux in a virtual machine and develop under Linux instead.

Comment: @PierU It still seems to be the case. Then we still have lldb which should be available, at least for certain optimization levels. But as I commented in my first comment, "complains that it does not work on M1" really says way too little. I would also note that there are plenty of separate SO questions and answers about those individual tools at M1 MacOS which tell a lot.

Comment: Another point where to be more specific: *"Most commands I tried don't seem to work for Fortran and/or M1."* Does it mean that some of those commands do not work for Fortran but do work for C or other languages or compilers? Please explain in detail. Is this really specific to Fortran? Which exact compiler?

Comment: I agree that the question is missing a lot of informations and details.

Comment: Added more details, let me know what other 'information and details' are missing.

Comment: Looks like the `-pg` option of `gcc` won't work on macOS (there are several SO questions that report that). That said there is some confusion between debugging and profiling: `lldb` is a debugger, not a profiler, so in itself it doesn't require the `-pg` option but rather the `-g` option.

Comment: I have no suggestion for profiling the code, though... it would be `gprof`, but without `-pg` at compile/link time it's useless.

Comment: ok, thanks for the clarification. I managed to step through the code with `lldb` but it cannot show me the variables, edited the question.

Comment: lldb may not support Fortran, unless it has changed recently: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44993207/14778592 https://stackoverflow.com/a/37999672/14778592

Comment: so are there any other options I could try on an M1-Mac?

Comment: I don't know... You may try asking on this forum, which is probably better suited than SO for extended discussions and recommendations : https://fortran-lang.discourse.group/ (this is kind of the "official unofficial" forum of the Fortran community)